# Why can't the app reviewer log into iOS app but everyone else can?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having a very frustrating problem where the iOS app reviewer is unable to log into my app during their review. I have never had this problem with any device or simulator (iPad/iPhone/various versions) and none of my Testflight users have had this problem either. My authentication and signin code is not that complicated and I am having a hard time figuring out how it's not working.

This is the code that is run when the sign in button is tapped:

```
        AuthManager.shared.signIn(email: email, password: password) { [weak self] result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .success)
                    let vc = TabBarViewController()
                    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    HapticsManager.shared.vibrate(for: .error)
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the AuthManager signIn function:

```
    public func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        self.auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil, let uid = result?.user.uid else {
                completion(.failure(AuthError.signInFailed))
                return
            }
            DatabaseManager.shared.findUser(uid: uid) { user in
                guard let user = user else {
                    completion(.failure(AuthError.signInFailed))
                    return
                }
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(user.username, forKey: "username")
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(user.uid, forKey: "uid")
                completion(.success(user))
                
            }
        }
    }
```

They are running the app on an iPad supposedly but I can not replicate the problem. I have cancelled and resubmitted as well as just updating the binary. Any ideas?

Comment: The bigger problem is that there are no reliable reproduction instructions or logs to examine.  "It's not working" isn't a workable problem statement on Stack Overflow.  We need to be able to reproduce the issue on our own using the provided instructions.  If you're depending on the fact that it doesn't work from App Store reviews, then the first comment stands.

Comment: No disagreements there however I'm finding it difficult to get any info from the reviewer.

Comment: @KnowNothing, are *you* able to log in using the credentials that you provided to the App Store reviewer?

Comment: @NRitH, yes absolutely, it is just a test account that I have used many times. Oddly enough, when the reviewer sends me a screenshot of the failed login attempt, the password field is not filled in. I want to give them the benefit of the doubt but unless they are deliberately deleting the password attempt, I can't see how they would end up with an empty password field.

Comment: Can your Submit button be enabled even when the password field is empty?

Comment: @NRitH, in the sign in button logic, there is some code to make sure both fields are filled. If one is empty, a popup alert shows.

Comment: You should copy and paste the credentials from the AppStore Connect page and test.  I had a problem where there was a space in the fields in AppStore Connect

Comment: @Paulw11, thanks I will check that